# Apex validation Form onsubmit not working

Tags: visualforce, validation

I have the following code that has form

```
<apex:form onsubmit="return activeAddrCkb()"> 
...
 <apex:commandButton action="{!step2}" value="Next"
                        styleClass="btn"  />
</apex:form >
```

JS

```
function activeAddrCkb(){
        alert("form truee");
        return chkCheckBoxes();
     }
```

the form validation is never called after I submit the form. It actually goes to the next page.(I never get that alert call) I need to make sure the form is validated and its true before going to the next page. If I do "onclick" at the button it works fine but not on the form submission

Answer (score 0):

i got it working by doing this

```
<apex:form onsubmit="return activeAddrCkb(this);">
```

I am not sure why It needed but it did